Why does my cat have a bald spot on the side of his neck?
It feels a little harder than the rest of his skin and there are bumps starting to develop around the bald spot.

you need to give a lot more information about yor cat,male,female,age,indoor or outdor cat?.and if possible a picture of the neck with the bald spot visible.

He is a two year old indoor male cat. and I am not sure how to add a picture

@Mari You can activate the editing mode by clicking on [edit] below your question. Then you'll see icon above the text like B I " { } and a dark square with some white triangles in it. That dark square is the "image" button. After clicking on it, you can upload an image from your device. But the file size is limited, so sometimes you have to crop a photo to make it smaller.
